# Electric panel distance from windows and/or gas service entry

Tags: electrical, hvac, gas, new-home

I can't find anything specific anywhere else, but what is the minimum distance a main electrical panel can be from a window when the panel is mounted on the outside of the house?

Additionally, is there any reg concerning the panel's horizontal distance from a gas meter on the same exterior wall?

I understand there are regs on "working space", but if these things (main panel, gas, A/C condenser, etc) exist on the same contiguous wall... are there any CODE restrictions on distance from EACH OTHER.  Can the working space more-or-less overlap?

If so, what are the relevant sources/code references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See page 17 of this .pdf from one of the most respected authorities on the NEC:
http://www.mikeholt.com/instructor2/img/product/pdf/11NEC101-1076-sample.pdf

I know links are frowned upon here, but Mr. Holt tends to keep pages available for many years.

Here is another good image:

[image]

© Mike Holt

Comment: Here is another good image:

Answer (score 1):

As far as the electrical equipment goes there is nothing beyond the working clearances. The equipment can be directly adjacent to either item.

Working clearance for a panel is 30" wide and 36" deep (in front). The equipment can be anywhere in the 30" wide space.

There may be a gas code clearance issue, but I am not familiar with that code.

Might I ask why you are asking?

Comment: The PM on my new home construction is saying that the electrical panel needs to be at least 2 (or is it 3?) feet from a window on the same wall.  This notion is severely limiting where they're willing to put the panel, and I was just wondering what the basis was.

Comment: Well, that depends on where your PM is getting his info, and why is he trying to undermine the knowledge of the electrician on the job? Knowing your location would also help, there may be a local restriction, but I doubt it. The window thing is nothing I've ever heard of. Now with regard to the service drop and drip loops (for an overhead service) there ARE restrictions to windows. Methinks your guys is confused.

Comment: This would be underground service from the curb transformer to the house.

Answer (score 1):

For the electrical, the working clearance must be kept. Working clearances can be overlapped. I'm not sure about gas regulations.

Comment: So, you're saying the edge of a panel must be at least 30 inches from an adjacent window?  Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: No, there is NO "at least 30 inches" rule. The 30" space can start right at the edge of the window, with the panel mounted right at that edge if that is what works for the job.

Comment: Correct. The window wouldn't be in the work space.

Comment: So, in other words, if you can stand in the 30" space, you're good, right?  Obviously, one can stand in front of a window, so no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Clearance requirements for PG&E are 36" from the gas riser to the electric panel edge.  Not sure if this helps you for your region.
  [image: gas_meter_clearance]